# Regenerate /etc/apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I accidentally, on a Ubuntu Server, deleted `/etc/apache2`. I hadn't altered any config in there, so I have not lost anything as long as I can regenerate it...
I tried `apt-get remove`ing and installing `apache2`, but it just says it's missing some files in `/etc/apache2` when I try to start it.
How can I regenerate it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most everything in there should be in the `apache2.2-common` package.  This'll force the re-installation of those config files:

```
dpkg --force-confmiss -i /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2.2-common*.deb
```

Start with that, and see if anything's still missing.

Comment: Apache doesn't like the new config:

`#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny <-- This line
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>`


is problematic:


`$ sudo service apache2 restart 
Syntax error on line 160 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
`

Comment: PS:

Sorry it's all so messy. The `<-- This Line` isn't actually in the config, I'm just showing 160.

Comment: Is it a problem that `mods-enabled` is empty?

Comment: I see on another Ubuntu server I have that all these mods are enabled:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40837996/Screenshots/18vx.png

Do I need to go through and enable all those by hand?

Comment: @JJ56 Those symlinks apparently aren't included files - the default module set is probably enabled by one of the installation scripts.  So, yes, you probably need to re-enable those.

Comment: I have all of them working except PHP5. Tried running `sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5`, but there is still no `php5.conf` or `php5.load` in `mods-enabled` or `mods-available` :(

Comment: any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Same deal - try `dpkg --force-confmiss -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libapache2-mod-php5*.deb`

Comment: Thanks so much! I was doing that in another window right before I saw the comment :)

Comment: Ahh crap. Now it tells me that `[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts` when I start it, and gives a 404 when I connect in a browser :(

Comment: The default site probably isn't enabled (same deal as the modules) - try `a2ensite default`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3499/discussion-between-jj56-and-shane-madden)